# How ca I create a scope that groups and fetch maximum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app, I have a model named `TopicEdition` with 2 attributes:
edition and an associated `Topic`.

The `topic_editions` table may look like

```
id | edition | topic_id
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 2       | 1
3  | 1       | 2
```

Now I need to get the list of `TopicEdition` having the highest edition for each topic.

Referring the table above, I should get back record with id 2 and 3.

I have tried to play around with `group` and `maximum` but without success.

My last attempt has been

```
TopicEdition.group(:topic_id).maximum(:edition)
```

How can I get what I need?

The followings work but it is kind of ugly

```
TopicEdition.find_by_sql 'SELECT * FROM topic_editions WHERE (topic_id, edition) 
IN (SELECT topic_id, MAX(edition) FROM topic_editions GROUP BY topic_id)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to use normal SQL to sort your query like this:

```
TopicEdition.group(:topic_id).order('MAX(edition)')
```

That will return only the last edition of each topic.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why but I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "topic_editions.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`